# What are Google Webfonts or Typekit alternatives to Avenir Next Pro?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

I'm looking for fonts, available from Google Webfonts (ideally) or Typekit, that would look similar to [**Avenir Next Pro**](http://www.linotype.com/90672/AvenirNext-family.html), specifically, **Bold** and **Demi**:

[image: Capital letters ABCDE, followed by lowercase a. Black on white]

[image: Capital letters ABCDE, followed by lowercase abcde, and numeral 1. Black on white]

Any similar-looking fonts, with good cross-browser rendering?

Comment: Here some good similar fonts. It's a list of similar fonts.
http://fontsup.com/similar/avenir-next-lt-pro.html

Answer (score 33):

Nunito is really quite different to Avenir - the letters are quite rounded.

I've done some serious work on this for a client and found the Google font [Lato](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato) is virtually indistinguishable from Avenir - you can literally put two words in the two fonts next to each other and not tell the difference.

Comment: I disagree here. The Q and the g are quite different, and it is enough that we were reluctant to use Lato as an alternative. You can see a comparison [here](https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T298X9PG9-F2XJ3KQQ5-c1860d59b5/font_comparison_1024.png)

Answer (score 16):

If you really want to use a Google Font, I highly suggest using NUNITO. It has 3 styles: Book, Normal, and Bold.  Here is a sample comparison between Book 300 and Avenir: https://web.archive.org/web/20140415053621/http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/new/font/avenir  The sentence length is a perfect match and x-height is great. Its only fault is that the ascenders and descenders are a tiny bit shorter.

Comment: Hmm... in lowercase it really doesn't look that similar, way too round-ish. I'll keep looking.

Comment: For small-sized copy sure but definitely not for titling.

Comment: Yes, *way* too rounded. Almost comic(-sans)ical.

Comment: And actually, **Nunito Sans** is the non-rounded equivalent, so it's much better - you can find it at [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito+Sans) or google [fonts web helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/nunito-sans?subsets=latin).

Answer (score 14):

I think [Museo Sans](https://typekit.com/fonts/museo-sans) is good enough:

[image]

On Google fonts there is also [Montserrat](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Montserrat) could be used for some words :)

[image]

Comment: I think Museo is beautiful, but when I tried it the browser rendering was less from perfect, specially in older Windows. If that's the main public, I'd test it thoroughly!

Answer (score 11):

I ended up using [Muli](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Muli) from [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Muli), I think it's pretty close:

[image]

Comment: What about PT Sans?

Comment: I tried the other ones and this definitely appears to be the most similar.

Comment: The Q is really quite different - but the graphic does not reflect the actual Q in Muli.

Comment: The font "Muli" is no longer available via Google Fonts.

Answer (score 11):

I have found Prompt to be very close to Avenir Next Pro within google fonts.

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Prompt

You can check the comparison here

[image]

Comment: I agree - it's super close!!!!

Comment: The biggest difference seems to be lowercase letter "a". Prompt also seems heavier than many other fonts for the same nominal weight.

Answer (score 7):

[Lato](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato) is also a comparable Google font:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Avenir is available for the web at [fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/avenir-next/demi/web-font)

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! It's not served though, I have to host it myself, right?

Comment: @julien_c You *can* however, they offer a plan to host it themselves. You would just use CSS or Javascript that that they give you to load them on your page (like Typekit or Webtype).

Comment: Just for the sake of saying, Google Web Fonts aren't much different than embedding it yourself on your own server. All they're doing is pointing to a CSS stylesheet that does pretty much the same types of declarations you'd do on your own stylesheet to embed them. Check out this link and you'll see all they're doing is referencing the font from their servers instead of local.

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tauri

Comment: @ChrisBurton License-wise, I'm not sure I am allowed to buy the font and just serve it myself as a Web font. Or am I?

Comment: @julien_c You mean pay a set fixed price and be abe to self host it?

Comment: @ChrisBurton Yes?

Comment: No, you'd have to pay a subscription based price (annual or monthly) to use Avenir from Fonts.com.

Comment: @julien_c you have to have a webfonts subscription. normally they'll serve you a javascript or css to point to, but you can choose to self-host on Pro plans. more info on pricing here - http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts/plans-and-pricing

Comment: @jamEs the advantage of using the CDN's offered by sites like that are that there's a change the user has encountered it elsewhere previously and the content is already cached, improving page-load

Answer (score 6):

FYI, for the lighter AvenirNext faces, don't overlook Ideal Sans.  They are virtually identical.  I haven't compared the heavier weights, but for the lighter, this is my go-to.  Yes, the lower-case g *is* different, but otherwise, it's pretty good.  I realize I'm necro-posting, but for anyone else that comes along:

[image: Comparing AvenirNext Light with IdealSans]

Comment: welcome to GD.SE! Necro posting is ok, as long as the answer is useful and answers the question. If you want to know more about the site check the [help].

Answer (score 4):

I believe that [Sofia Pro Light](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/sofia-pro) from Font Squirrel is a close match.

[image]

Comment: nice looking font but from the license, "Licensee may not link the Font to web sites using the @font-face selector in CSS. An extended license may be available for an additional fee."

Comment: At least lowercase "a" and "e" look pretty different from Avenir.

Answer (score 4):

The question is by now three years old, but I really feel I should mention League Spartan from the [League of Movable Type](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com). It's not from Google Fonts, but it's free and Open Source:

> The League has given only the most well-made, free & open-source,
> @font-face ready fonts

It's available in 8 different styles. [image]

Comment: Actually, League Spartan is available in eight weights now, plus a variable font.

Comment: @BertD That is good news!

Answer (score 4):

No no, Nunito or Lato are very different to my eyes. I've done a lot of work around this and found the below fonts pretty similar if treated with attention (font size, weight, letter spacing):

- [Soleil](https://typekit.com/fonts/soleil)
- [Mr Eaves XL](https://typekit.com/fonts/mr-eaves-xl)
- [Filson](https://typekit.com/fonts/filson)
- [Gibson](https://typekit.com/fonts/gibson)
- [Museo Sans](https://typekit.com/fonts/museo-sans)

(from TypeKit)

Comment: would you mind adding some images to help us understand why those are a good choice without having to get out of GD.SE? Also link rot is a problem, if those links die your answer loses relevance

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best place but you wont go far wrong with either of these

[OpenSans](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Open+Sans):

[image]

[SourceSans](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Except for the uppercase "Q" and the lower height of the ascenders, Proxima Nova on Typekit is quite close.

Comment: Lower case "a" is slightly different too, but I agree this is an excellent alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I came across [Open Sans](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans), and it seems like the uppercase J is the only letter that's obviously different.

Answer (score 2):

[Nunito](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Nunito) is an excellent alternative to Avenir. The ascenders are slightly higher in Avenir but even the most persnickety designer would have a hard time telling them apart.  It can be found at http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Nunito it has 3 styles created by Vernon Adams

**Avenir**

[image]

**Nunito (Book 300)**

[image]

Source: http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/new/font/avenir

Comment: Nunito is a rounded face. At anything above the sizes shown here, the face would look very different.

Comment: Would look pretty much the same for blind people, apart from that, nah.

Comment: "Nunito Sans" is the version with the non-rounded terminals: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito+Sans?selection.family=Nunito+Sans

Answer (score 2):

I've been hunting for a good replacement for this. Open Sans, Source Sans Pro, and all the other popular sans-serif fonts on Google Fonts are really nothing like Avenir Next. Avenir Next is a thin font. I used [this](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Sans+Serif&thickness=1) filtering on Google fonts to find similar thin sans-serif fonts. I found two: Heebo and Yantramanav. Using these with the Thin or Light style gets me pretty close to Avenir Next.

Comment: Please include screenshots of the two recommended fonts you have mentioned.

Comment: Great choices.  Beats all of the other Google Fonts suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think **Gibson** on Typekit looks more similar than any of the other suggestions here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Futura](https://typekit.com/fonts/futura-pt) as an alternative to Avenir or Avenir Next

Answer (score -2):

In google font
try POPPINS is best answer

Comment: Hello Kekeman Kayasawa, welcome to GD.SE. Could you please include a screenshot of and a link to the typeface? That way, viewers can judge whether your option is a good one without having to search the Google fonts site themselves. Thanks. If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!