# Substitute for Avenir (Google webfont or Typekit)

Tags: website-design, web-fonts, font-recommendation

## Question

I'm looking for fonts, available from Google Webfonts or Typekit, that would look similar to **Avenir**.

[image]

## Background

I'm building a site using Squarespace

My friend told me to use **Avenir for headings** and shorter texts. Any of these three:

- [Avenir 85 Heavy](http://www.linotype.com/43922/AvenirPro85Heavy-product.html)
- [Avenir 65 Medium](https://www.linotype.com/1245906/avenir-65-medium-product.html)
- [Avenir 55 Roman](https://www.linotype.com/1245898/avenir-55-roman-product.html)

Squarespace does not have Avenir though. Squarespace *does* have support for Google webfonts and typekit.

Should I use **Minion for the text body**?

- [Minion Regular](http://www.linotype.com/172075/MinionProCaptionRegular-product.html)
- **[Minion Bold](http://www.linotype.com/172039/MinionProBoldCaption-product.html)**

Squarespace does have *Minion* so I think I can use that one instead.

---

PS. Similar question:
[What are Google Webfonts or Typekit alternatives to Avenir Next Pro?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16036/what-are-google-webfonts-or-typekit-alternatives-to-avenir-next-pro)

Comment: I see you saw the question about alternatives to Avenir Next Pro...is this not a duplicate? Avenir and Avenir Next will be identical to the casual viewer ('Next'-type weights are usually minor refinements, more characters, or more weights).

Comment: Looks like this topic already exists: 
[http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16036/what-are-google-webfonts-or-typekit-alternatives-to-avenir-next-pro][1]


  [1]: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16036/what-are-google-webfonts-or-typekit-alternatives-to-avenir-next-pro

Comment: Your friend told you to use Avenir? Does that mean you absolutely have to, or is it because you friend likes Avenir? On the comments below it sounds like you want a font looking exactly like Avenir, that isn't possible, because then it would be Avenir... No regular person will see the difference in fonts, and no one will know that you wanted to use Avenir, so what is the big fuzz about the R or G being different. I'm just trying to understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nunito**

http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/new/font/avenir

> Nunito is an excellent match to Avenir. The ascenders are slightly higher in Avenir but even the most persnickety designer would have a hard time telling them apart.

Comment: The 'R' is *very* different. I just don't think there is a stellar free alternative out there.

Comment: Just saw that several were very different. changed my mind to **Proxima Nova** Regular. Better?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there is a really obvious choice to replace Avenir in Google Fonts.

However, I recently had to ask myself this question, and my answer was and is [Lato](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato):

[image: Lato screenshot]

The letters occupy similar amounts of space, the letterforms are in the right ballpark, and the font has a robust set of weights/italics for you to use.

Comment: g looks very different, bad choice.

Comment: @jacob please be nice to the people, who are making an effort to help you …

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few choices:

Avenir
[image: Avenir sample]

Gibson
[image: Gibson Sample]

Proxima Nova
[image: Proxima nova sample]

Montserrat
[image: Montserrat sample]

Gibson and Proxima are on typekit, Montserrat on Google Fonts

Answer (score 2):

Raleway could also be a good contender

[Raleway specimen page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway)

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the font.

Answer (score 1):

Prompt is also good, yet a bit larger.

[Prompt specimen page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Prompt)

Comment: When referencing a font please include a screenshot of said font.

Answer (score 0):

[image: comparaison Avenir/Lato/Nunito]

I choosed Nunito at first but Lato seems to be the closest as i see now.

Comment: The first sample is NOT avenir. Compare to the links in the initial question.